# Extract highest value for two other variables - R code

Tags: r

Test assignment: Highest amount of free wine given by day/driver combination?

note: need perform this work with tidyverse library only - can't load any other library

Need help with my code:

```
pizza %>%
  select(day,driver,free_wine)%>%
  group_by(day,driver)%>%
  summarise(n=sum(free_wine,na.rm = TRUE),.groups = 'drop')
```

My output is not correct (showing multiple line items for each day). I understand that I need a code line to show max value by day and driver here but unable to figure out how to do it without impacting groupby configuration

Expected out should be one row for each day showing max value -

Example

**Day** **Driver** **n**
Friday Sam 20
Thursday Tom 12
Wenesday Rick 15

Comment: Use `max` instead of `sum`? `summarise(free_wine=max(free_wine,na.rm = TRUE), etc)`. And you don't need to `select` first, `group_by` and `summarise` will do it for you.

Comment: @RuiBarradas - max doesn't work because there are multiples values under each day and driver that needs to be added to get a total for each day under a driver then I need to extract that max value for each day and publish driver name for that max value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following. After adding the `free_wine` amounts per driver and day, `filter` the maximal values.

```
pizza %>%
  group_by(day, driver) %>%
  summarise(free_wine = sum(free_wine, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'keep') %>%
  filter(free_wine == max(free_wine))
```

An alternative is to drop the groups an group again but this time by year only.

```
pizza %>%
  group_by(day, driver)%>%
  summarise(free_wine = sum(free_wine,na.rm = TRUE),.groups = 'drop') %>%
  group_by(day) %>%
  filter(free_wine == max(free_wine))
```

Comment: adding this filter only shows one day with max value - I am looking to get a output for each day with their max value

Comment: @PrashantPawar I believe it's just a matter of changing `.groups = 'keep'`. Or drop the groups and group again. Try it and say if it solved the problem.