# How to find highest variable based on a combination of 2 other variables

Tags: r

Using the pizza dataset, I need to find the highest amount of free wine given by day/driver combination? This is the code I tried but it only provided an output for the day and driver.

```
Q5 <- pizza %>% select(day, driver, free_wine) %>% arrange(desc(free_wine)) %>% group_by(day, driver) %>% summarise() Q5
```

I've included an image of what it's meant to look like and an extra image containing a screenshot of my code/output. I think the day and driver column I created is correct. I need help bringing out the free wine column and making sure that these variables show up as a combination of day/driver and are also converted to integers as well.
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhro7.png)

Comment: see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71500448/extract-highest-value-for-two-other-variables-r-code?rq=2